# Leaflet.js Canvas click indexing doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet

I'm trying to draw 5000 squares on top of a virtual hockey field using Leaflet.js with a Simple CRS and the Canvas element.

For inspiration and getting started, I studied the sourcecode of http://build-failed.blogspot.nl/2012/04/maps-and-boardgames-part-3-client-side.html, but this works with hexagons and I want squares.

After some hacking, I ended up with a grid of squares on top of the hockeyfield.

Clicking squares doesn't work as intended however.

The grid generating code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        var square = createSquare(s, i, j);
        squares.push(square);
        squaresIndexed['' + i + ',' + j] = square;
    }
}
```

The squaresIndexed array holds a copy of all squares and is used for interaction later on in Leaflet's click handler:

```
    map.on('click', function(e) {
        var offset = projections.LatLongToPixelXY_optimized(startlat, startLon, levelOfDetail);
        var result = projections.LatLongToPixelXY_optimized(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng, levelOfDetail);

        result.x = result.x - offset.x +200;
        result.y = result.y - offset.y +200;

        s = new squareDefinition();
        var uv = s.getReferencePoint(result.x, result.y);
        var square = squaresIndexed['' + uv.u + ',' + uv.v];

        console.log('square', square);
        L.marker([square.center.lat, square.center.lng]).addTo(map);
        selectedSquare = new L.Polygon(square.coordinates);
        map.addLayer(selectedSquare);
    });
```

The square is 'fetched' back from the squareIndexed array by using the 'reverse' of squareDefiniton.getPixelCoordinates() which is squareDefinition.getReferencePoint()

This is where it seems to go wrong in my opinion. I suspect it has to do with the 'offset' being off and I can't figure out how to correct for it.

To see it in effect, have a look at the jsfiddle I composed, and zoom out maximally. Then click on the field and see the selection appear on the far left: http://jsfiddle.net/gnijholt/wzennher/2/

As stated, this code is in the process of quick and dirty hacking so sorry for any ugliness or stupidity.

Thanks a lot to anyone who dare look into this!

Answer (score 0):

OK after some rethinking, I figured out that since it's using CRS.simple, all lat/lon stuff should be removed. Now it kind of works. I can update the fiddle if interested.